# Python Airlflow Google Cloud Storage library import error

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage, airflow

I want to create an airflow DAG to transfer files to cloud storage but I'm running into a problem importing Google Cloud libraries.
Libraries I want to use:

```
from airflow.providers.google.cloud.operators.gcs import GCSCreateBucketOperator, GCSDeleteBucketOperator
from airflow.providers.google.cloud.operators.gcs import GCSCreateBucketOperator
from airflow.providers.google.cloud.transfers.gcs_to_local import GCSToLocalFilesystemOperator
from airflow.providers.google.cloud.transfers.local_to_gcs import LocalFilesystemToGCSOperator
```

I want to create an airflow DAG to transfer files to cloud storage but I'm running into a problem importing Google Cloud libraries.
Libraries I want to use:

The error I got:

```
pkg_resources.ContextualVersionConflict: (protobuf 4.21.9 (/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages), Requirement.parse('protobuf<4.0.0dev'), {'google-cloud-secret-manager'})
```

I tried `pip install googleapis-common-protos --upgrade` to fix the problem but still the same problem persists

Comment: You have this problem on your local machine ?

Comment: Which version of `Airflow` are you using ?

Comment: Yes I am having the problem on my local machine and my Airflow version is 2.4.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your virtual env, you can try to install the `Apache Airflow` package with extra `gcp` to prevent depencencies conflicts :

Example with `pip` :

requirements.txt file

```
apache-airflow[gcp]==2.4.2
```

`pip` command :

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

You can also use another package manager with `Python` like [pipenv](https://pipenv.pypa.io/en/latest/) and `PipFile` :

```
apache-airflow = { version = "==2.4.2", extras = ["gcp"] }
```

In all the cases, I really recommend you to use a virtual env to isolate the packages for your current project and to prevent conflict on installed packages.

Comment: Thank you very much!! This solved my problem. Is the problem caused by a package conflict?

Comment: You are very welcome :), yes the issue was due to a package conflict.